# Почему не работает OnMouseEnter, ...Over, ...Exit?

Tags: unity3d

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

есть 2 объекта: сфера и платформа, сфера и на ней HoverLight, платформа и на ней HoverLight. При этом у платформы меш в дочернем объекте. На сфере скрипт HoverLight работает, а в на платформе нет, и вопрос в том, почему так происходит?